# How to called google earth function using vb 

Tags: vb.net, google-earth

i build a software using **vb** , and now , i want to call some function in **google earth** ,

what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Earth API](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/faq.html) is JavaScript based, so it doesn't matter what your server is written in; just write the JavaScript you want in your client web-pages.

If you are not writing a web page, this is probably the wrong API. For rich clients, consider things like MapPoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using winforms then you could always add the type library and then call the COM functions as required. 
http://earth.google.com/comapi/

That said the COM API is now depreciated so developing for it might be a waste of time...
http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2010/09/the_google_earth_com_api_is_being_p.html

It is now recommended to use the javascript api for Google Earth applcations - you can see an example control library for windows applications using the js api here, it is .NET but c# rather than VB -

http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/

Answer (score 0):

Google seems determined to push people off the COM API, as every "link" to documentation gets redirected to the same "Sunset for the Google Earth COM API" Google Geo Developers Blog.

8-/

I'm curious why Google hasn't developed a better and clearer API to GE. I presume it's something marketing related. It seems to me they'd really capture a larger development audience with a straight-forward, simplistic API.  I find some of the calls a little head scratching.

In any event, has someone created any kind of .NET wrapper class to abstract the JS API? I've been rooting around looking for one, but so far no go.